# Creating instance of labelled fields data type

Tags: haskell, types, label, field

How do I create an instance of a "labelled fields data type"?

```
data InputData = InputData { events :: [Event], newResources :: [Resource] }
myInputData :: InputData
myInputData = ???
```

Comment: @sisif: your question is very unclear

Comment: It's pretty clear to me; he wants to know how to use the data constructor so defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where myInputData = InputData {events=[], newResources=[]}
```

Comment: Also `InputData {newResources=[], events=[]}` and `InputData [event1, event2] [newResource1, newResource2]` work too.